# Trying to compare two strings in Java using equals()

Tags: java

I have tried a number of ways to compare two strings of 'phone numbers' and none seem to pass the tests. 
the code I am currently using:

```
public boolean equals (PhoneNumber other) {     
    boolean results = other.equals(digits);
    return results;
}
```

The test I am trying to pass without hard coding for it:

```
p = new PhoneNumber("5551212");
    p2 = new PhoneNumber("5551212", "Home");
    displayResults(p.equals(p2));
    p.setDigits("1234123");
    displayResults(p.equals(p2) == false);
```

Comment: You need to override the `.equals` for the `PhoneNumber` class

Comment: Is `digits` a string? Did you mean `other.digits.equals(digits)`? Also note that your method doesn't override `Object.equals()`, so it's useless for collections.

Comment: Ooooooh thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Two separate problems:

[1] digits is a string; other is a phonenumber. these will NEVER be equal. What you're presumably looking for, is `other.digits.equals(this.digits)`. Now we're comparing the digits of phone number A with the digits of phone number B: Apples and apples. That has a chance of working out.

[2] the equals method's signature is `public boolean equals(Object other)`. Your equals method has a different signature, which means, it is an entirely different method with no relation whatsoever to the real equals method.. other than the coincidence that it so happens to share a name with it. It means your 'fake' equals method would not be used by other code that uses equals methods. Such as the `contains` method of an arraylist, for example. The solution is to make that equals method have as argument `Object other`.

[3] when you do that, you won't be able to call `.digits` on `other`; after all, only phonenumbers have digits; any random object isn't guaranteed to. The solution is to cast the `other`, but only do that after checking if it is a phonenumber:

```
public boolean equals(PhoneNumber other) {
    if (!(other instanceof PhoneNumber)) {
        // somebody is comparing apples to oranges. Obviously, then...
        return false;
    }
    return ((PhoneNumber) other).digits.equals(this.digits);
}
```

note also that for proper operation of such an object in, say, `HashSet`, you must always override both the `hashCode` and the `equals` method, or neither.

[Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) automates all this stuff, you may be interested in this.